# Javascript, merging two objects of 1400 items each, fastest way?

Tags: arrays, performance, loops, for-loop, javascript-objects

For a structure like this

```
var arr = [];
arr[0] = {};
arr[0].p1 = [];
arr[0].p1[0] = 'hola arr0 p1';
arr[0].p2 = [];
arr[0].p2[0] = 'hola arr0 p2';
arr[1] = {};
arr[1].p1 = [];
arr[1].p1[0] = 'hola arr1 p1';
arr[1].p2 = [];
arr[1].p2[0] = 'hola arr1 p2';
arr[2] = {};
arr[2].p1 = [];
arr[2].p1[0] = 'hola arr2 p1';
arr[2].p3 = [];
arr[2].p3[0] = 'hola arr2 p3';
arr[3] = {};
arr[3].p2 = [];
arr[3].p2[0] = 'hola arr3 p2';
arr[3].p3 = [];
arr[3].p3[0] = 'hola arr3 p3';
arr[4] = {};
arr[4].p1 = [];
arr[4].p1[0] = 'hola arr4 p1';
arr[4].p4 = [];
arr[4].p4[0] = 'hola arr4 p4';
```

I want to merge the objects so that at the end I have all the information condensed in a single object.
This code works:

```
for (let a=1;a<arr.length; a++){
    for (let i in arr[0]) {
        for (let j in arr[a]) {
        if (i === j) {
        arr[0][i][a] = arr[a][j][0];
        delete arr[a][j];
      }
        }
    }

    for (let j in arr[a]) {
        arr[0][j] = [];
        arr[0][j][a] = arr[a][j][0];
    delete arr[a][j];
    }

}

console.log(arr)
```

And I get the output that I want to.

https://jsfiddle.net/jb73tur4/

The problem is that in my real code arr[0] has 1500 keys and arr[1] has 1300 keys. Looping through the two means 1500x1300 iterations, which freezes the browser.

**Is there any way to do this? to accelerate this somehow?**

Answer (score 0):

If you anticipate that many iterations, check out the Web Worker API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers), which will allow you to run the computation in the background and prevent the page from freezing.

Comment: But it is a good idea? Are this dimensions compatible with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

By taking advantage of the object-instead-of-array characteristics, this entails many less iterations

https://jsfiddle.net/jb73tur4/2/

```
for (var a = 1; a < arr.length; a++) {
  for (let p in arr[a]) {
    if (arr[0][p]) {
      arr[0][p][a] = arr[a][p][0];
      delete arr[a][p];
    }
  }

  let new_str = {};
  for (let p in arr[a]) {
    new_str[p] = [];
    new_str[p][a] = arr[a][p][0];
  }
  Object.assign(arr[0], new_str);
  delete arr[a];
}

console.log(arr)
```